# Print multiple char variables in one line?

Tags: java, char

So I was just wondering if there was a way to print out multiple `char` variables in one line that does not add the Unicode together that a traditional print statement does.

For example:

```
char a ='A'; 
char b ='B'; 
char c ='C';
System.out.println(a+b+c); <--- This spits out an integer of the sum of the characters
```

Comment: You want a `String`, not to add three chars together. A `char` is an unsigned 16-bit integer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
System.out.println(a+""+b+""+c);
```

or:

```
System.out.printf("%c%c%c\n", a, b, c);
```

Comment: Well that was fast. Seems simple enough. Thanks

Comment: I'd use a StringBuilder over the awkward String concatenation (just a preference), but +1 for the printf answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the String constructors, to build a string from an array of chars.

```
System.out.println(new String(new char[]{a,b,c}));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `println()` method you invoked is one that accepts an `int` argument.

With variable of type `char` and a method that accepts `int`, the `char`s are [widened](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) to `int`s. They are added up before being returned as an `int` result.

You need to use the overloaded `println()` method that accepts a `String`. To achieve that you need to use `String` concatenation. Use the `+` operator with a `String` and any other type, `char` in this case.

```
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c); // or whatever format
```

Answer (score 1):

This will serve : `System.out.println(String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b) + String.valueOf(c));`.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(a).append(b).append(c).toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

System.out.print(a);System.out.print(b);System.out.print(c) //without space